# how to center div inside div horizontally and inner div have width of its text content?

Tags: html, css

Outer div have certain width. But inner div should have the width equal to its text content and inner div should be horizontally centered

```
<div id="outer">
<div id="inner">
Hello....
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: By definition the inner div will have the width equal to its text content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set inner `div` as `display:inline-block` and parent `text-align:center`

```css
#outer {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center
}
#inner {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    Hello....
  </div>
</div>
```